# What does this error while running 'middleman' mean?

Tags: middleman

I came across this middleman [package](https://github.com/thenickcox/Middleman-Skeleton) and tried to run it with `bundle exec middleman server` but get this back in the terminal...

```
The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure. Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.

== The Middleman is loading
== Port 4567 is unavailable. Either close the instance of Middleman already running on 4567 or start this Middleman on a new port with: --port=4568
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either close the instance of Middleman already running on 4567 or start this Middleman on a new port with: --port=4568

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*I found the answer in the [middleman forum](http://forum.middlemanapp.com/t/what-does-this-error-while-running-middleman-mean/1243/3)... 
if you do:*

`lsof -i: <Port number>` Enter your Port # here; In my case 4567"

The above, will output a PID #, then if you enter that in the below

`kill -9 <PID here>`

You'll be able to restart your server.

Answer (score 5):

The **first error** is regarding the source declaration in your Gemfile.

It probably says

`source :rubygems`

at the top. Change this line to

`source "https://rubygems.org"`

or use `http://rubygems.org` if you don’t have OpenSSL installed.

The **second error** means, that there is already something else running on port 4567, which is the default middleman port. Maybe you have another middleman installation running. Make sure to either shut that one down or start middleman with an explicit port (that has to be free as well of course) like:

`bundle exec middleman --port 5000`

If you cant’f find the running middleman instance, try searching for ruby processes that could be using the port with `ps ax | grep ruby`. This will give you the process ID that you can then use kill the process: `kill <id>`. Hope that helps!